# FORM submission gives empty form in IE browser when passed via AJAX in coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, coldfusion

I have two `cfm` pages, when I submit from one page to another via `AJAX` in Internet Explorer, the form structure is received as empty.

It is working fine for all other browsers i.e., Chrome and FF.

This issue is for all versions of IE 9,10,11.

When I submit this form without the AJAX call, it is getting submitted and I get the form too.

Can anyone help? Below is the code for my AJAX call.

```
$("form").submit(function() {           
    //check if form fields are valid
    var isValid = validateDetails();
    if (isValid) {
        $('#tab1').html('<div style="margin-top:100px;" align="center">Loading ...<br/><br/><img src="/rpnet/images/ajax-loader.gif"/></div>');
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            $("#tab1").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
 <form action="/rpnet/iStat/rmtconf-dev.cfm?type=4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="editapplicant">
         <input name="AP_NUMBER" type="hidden" value="<cfoutput>#URL.AP_NUMBER#</cfoutput>">
            <ul id="threecolumn1" class="threecolumn">
                    <li>Name:</li>
                    <li>Address:</li>
                    <li>City:</li>
                    <li>State:</li>
                    <li>Zip:</li>
                    <li>Daytime Phone:</li>
                    <li>Home Phone:</li>
                    <li>Fax:</li>
                    <li>Email:</li>
                    <li>DOB:</li>
                    <li>SSN:</li>
                    <li>Policy / Claim #:</li>
                </ul>
           <cfoutput>
               <ul id="threecolumn2" class="threecolumn">
                        <li><cfif SESSION.TESTMODE eq 1>#TEST_NAME#<cfelse>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_NAME#</cfif></li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_ADDRESS#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_CITY#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_ST#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_ZIP#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_DAYPHONE#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_PHONE1#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_FAX#</li>
                        <li>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_PT_EMAIL#</li>
                        <li><cfif SESSION.TESTMODE eq 1>#DateFormat(TEST_DOB,"mm/dd/yyyy")#<cfelse>#DateFormat(GetApplicantInfo.AP_DOB,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</cfif></li>
                        <li><cfif SESSION.TESTMODE eq 1>#TEST_SSN#<cfelse>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_SSN#</cfif></li>
                        <li><cfif SESSION.TESTMODE eq 1>#TEST_FILE_NUMBER#<cfelse>#GetApplicantInfo.AP_FILE_NUMBER#</cfif></li>
                    </ul>
                </cfoutput>
             <ul id="threecolumn3" class="threecolumn">
                    <li><input name="NAME" id="NAME" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="ADDRESS" id="ADDRESS" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="CITY" id="CITY" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="STATE" id="STATE" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');" type="text" size="5" maxlength="2"></li>
                    <li><input name="ZIP" id="ZIP" type="text" size="11" maxlength="10"></li>
                    <li><input name="DAYPHONE" id="DAYPHONE" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="PHONE" id="PHONE" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="FAX" id="FAX" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL"type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="DOB" id="DOB" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="SSN" id="SSN" type="text" size="30"></li>
                    <li><input name="POLICYNUM" id="POLICYNUM" type="text" size="30"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><input class="submitButton" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Changes"><input class="submitButton" name="Clear" type="reset" id="Clear" value="Clear All"></li>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you please add your form?

Comment: Please check the form have added it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, but the solution is little weird,
Have removed the records loading code from the submit function and the form submits fine.

Below is the code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {           
  //check if form fields are valid
  var isValid = validateDetails();
  if (isValid) {
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
          $("#tab1").html(data);
      });
    return false;
   }
  return false;
});
```

Why did this happen any idea?

Comment: I have tried your code and its working even with the loading code. Make sure that you have added code for [preventing the default behavior of form](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). Please provide the element with id tab1 if you still facing the same problem (Update it on your question).